# MariaDB does not install on Centos7

Tags: database, mariadb, centos7

Launched an centos7 instance on aws with run commands passing it over in user data.

What I noticed the mariadb does not get installed. I am able to ssh into the instance.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATABASE_PASS='admin123'
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install epel-release -y
sudo yum install git zip unzip -y
sudo yum install mariadb-server -y


# starting & enabling mariadb-server
sudo systemctl start mariadb
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
cd /tmp/
git clone -b vp-rem https://github.com/devopshydclub/vprofile-repo.git
#restore the dump file for the application
sudo mysqladmin -u root password "$DATABASE_PASS"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$DATABASE_PASS') WHERE User='root'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "create database accounts"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "grant all privileges on accounts.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'admin123'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "grant all privileges on accounts.* TO 'admin'@'%' identified by 'admin123'"
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" accounts < /tmp/vprofile-repo/src/main/resources/db_backup.sql
sudo mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"

# Restart mariadb-server
sudo systemctl restart mariadb


#starting the firewall and allowing the mariadb to access from port no. 3306
sudo systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

above is the run command passed to user data. When i type systemctl status mariadb i get the following output 'Unit mariadb.service could not be found.'

I have checked online and other threads the error is not clear, please can you help

Comment: please follow the instruction on the homepage https://mariadb.com/de/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

Comment: that ^.  except it's a little out of date; choice one of the long term support releases (10.6 or 10.11)